# Phonegap Android Fingerprint Auth Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, fingerprint

I am currently creating a mobile app with Adobe Phonegap and I am trying to lock a page of the app so that it can only be accessed by fingerprint.

I am completely new to incorporating plugins and using them.

I have been following tutorials such as the ones present on the github of the plugin:

https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth#module_fingerprintauth.config

I have successfully installed the plugin with the command:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth
```

However I don't how to set up and use the plugin.

I have tried to check if the fingerprint hardware is available.

Sample code is actually given and it looks like so:

```
FingerprintAuth.isAvailable(isAvailableSuccess, isAvailableError);

/**
* @return {
*      isAvailable:boolean,
*      isHardwareDetected:boolean,
*      hasEnrolledFingerprints:boolean
*   }
*/

function isAvailableSuccess(result) 
{
    console.log("FingerprintAuth available: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    if (result.isAvailable) 
    {
       var encryptConfig = {}; // See config object for required parameters
       FingerprintAuth.encrypt(encryptConfig, encryptSuccessCallback, encryptErrorCallback);
    }
}

function isAvailableError(message) 
{
    console.log("isAvailableError(): " + message);
}
```

I keep getting errors such as:

```
Error: exec proxy not found for :: FingerprintAuth :: availability
```

and

```
isAvailableError(): Missing Command Error
```

Am I missing a trick?
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on the Phonegap App Developer app? If yes it will not work because apparently, even though it runs on the phone, it still uses the browser plugin, which means that the Android fingerprint native API is not available. 
Run:

> phonegap build android

And you should be able to deploy the APK to your phone and have it working.

Comment: I have actually got this to work thanks for your help though. I really appreciate it.